# jasmine mocks not used in setImmediate

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a function whose core logic is run in a `setImmediate` like so:

code:

```
public async myFunc() {
    setImmediate(async () => {
        // core logic
        someModule.foo();
    });
}
```

unit test:

```
const mock1: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(...);
const mock2: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(someModule, 'foo');

myFunc().then(() => {
    expect(someModule.foo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
});
```

My test is failing with `someModule.foo was called 0 times`. When I debugged the test, the reason it's failing is because the mock is not being used by the actual code. The whole test fails because instead of using `mock2`, the test uses the actual production logic. If I remove the `setImmediate` however, the test works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: My thought is that it is impossible to get around this because the unit test itself is on the call stack, so the setImmediate will never be executed before the unit test.